# Как подменить текущую директорию для процесса IIS?

Tags: windows, iis

Для работы сайта под IIS потребовалась старая нативная библиотека, написанная на С. В этой библиотеке есть баг, пару временных файлов она создаёт в текущей директории.
Можно ли при помощи фич IIS или Windows-а сделать так, чтобы файлы писались в другую директорию?

P.S. Когда работал под Vista-ой заметил, что процессы, установленные в поддиректорию "Program Files" и пытающиеся писать в эту же директорию без админских прав, на самом деле, писали в папку "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Program files\MyProgram".

Answer (score 1):

НЕ факт что сработает, но можно попробовать:

**Вариант 1**

В вашей рабочей папке (та кот должна редиректить) добавить `web.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://sub.domain.com/logs/" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Вариант 2 через  GUI:**

Выбрать папку :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

задать путь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Дайте нужные права пользователю, под которым работает пул IISа, под которым работает приложение и все.